# To show that f : V $\to$ V is nilpotent iff there is an ordered basis of V with respect to f in this form

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let W be a vector space. dim(W) = n

If $f$ is linear, show $f$ is nilpotent if and only if there is an ordered basis of W with respect to which the matrix of $f$ is an n x n matrix whose subdiagonal entries are 1 and the rest of the entries are 0.

---

I'm not sure how to write out matrices like that on this site sorry.

so for any m < n.    $f^m$ $\neq$ 0

I also see a theorem saying if $f$ is nilpotent  there is an ordered basis of W with respect to which the matrix of $f$ is a Jordan block Matrix for the eigenvalue 0. But cant see how to use it to help me out.

Does getting the nth  or n-1th power of the matrix show anything for the converse.

Any help would be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: What if $f$ is the null function? No matter which basis you take, the matrix of $f$ with respect to that basis will be the null matrix.

Comment: What you *can* show is that there is a basis with respect to which the matrix representation of $f$ has all zeros, *except perhaps* for the subdiagonal entries, each of which is either $0$ or $1$.